# How to add PHP inside SQL Query in PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a Array named `$category` which has values in string format. 
I want to add it in query such that I can filter the results by category.

Something Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ig_accounts WHERE category IN (Array Values here)
```

So the query becomes something like:

```
SELECT * FROM ig_accounts WHERE category IN ('text','fashion','sports')
```

Right now I am using this, which has an error:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ig_accounts WHERE category IN (".
                for($i=0;$i<$category[NULL];$i++)
                {
                echo '$category[$i]';   
                }
                .")";
```

Comment: make your for loop outer of the query and format it properly.

Comment: Don't `echo`, concatenate. Use `foreach` to. What is `$category[NULL]`?

Comment: I have to use Loop in the Query because the values will be dynamic depending upon what Categories the User has Selected.

Comment: In `for` do `$query .=` also use `"` variables in single quotes aren't processed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the implode function depending on the structure of your array

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ig_accounts WHERE category IN ('" . implode("','", $category) . "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ig_accounts WHERE category IN ('" . implode("','", $category) . "')";
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php
>   implode — Join array elements with a string

```
<?php
$a1 = array("1","2","3");
echo "a1 is: '".implode("','",$a1)."'<br>";

?>

will produce:
===========
a1 is: '1','2','3'
```

Comment: you have some missing simple quote around the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Is `$category` provided by the user?  If so, beware, and consider prepared statements.  Try the following.

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM ig_accounts WHERE category IN ('.implode(',', array_fill(0,count($category ), '?')).')';
$stmt=$myDB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($category );
```

Reference http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` to make the string from an array. This is the way how can you do the thing.

```
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($category); $i++){
    $arr[] = $category[$i];
}
$in = join(" , ", $arr);
$query = "SELECT * FROM ig_accounts WHERE category IN (".$in.")";
```

Comment: I guess this will work, In C++ i use for(i=0;i<=variable[NULL];i++) How do i specify last value in php that is NULL ?

Comment: I mean how to get size of array directly in PHP,

Comment: use `count()` function.

Comment: @shobhit99, I update my answer how you want it to be.